# How to disable checkboxes in a ListView (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, listview, checkbox

In my UserForm I initialize a ListView with data from database:

This is just a code snippet:

```
While Not rsRL.EOF
  If rsRL("Status").Value = 1 Then
     .ListItems.Add , , rsRL("ID")
     .ListItems(.ListItems.Count).tag = rsRL("RL_Status")
  Else
    // Here I want to disable the checkbox of the corresponding data            
  End If
  .ListItems(.ListItems.Count).ListSubItems.Add , , rsRL("Name")
  .ListItems(.ListItems.Count).ListSubItems.Add , , rsRL("Datum")
  .ListItems(.ListItems.Count).ListSubItems.Add , , rsRL("Typ")

  If rsRL("RL_Status").Value = True Then
      .ListItems(.ListItems.Count).Checked = True
  End If
  rsRL.MoveNext
Wend
```

In else-sector I just want to display the ID without the checkbox or to disable the checkbox so that it is not clickable! How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The following is to hide the Checkbox and set the value to default (if you don't unload the form or user was available to click it *prior to analyze if it should be hidden with no valid selection*)

```
CheckBox.Visible = False
CheckBox.Value = False
```

Comment: Did you try ListView.Checkbox.Visible= False? [More info here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?695161-Checkbox-in-listview)

Comment: this is not available in excel 2010